# VectorDrawableCompat Resources$NotFoundException under older versions of Android

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-vectordrawable

I'm switching to vector drawables and they are working pretty well even on older Android versions. My app targets 4+. I switched one of my notifications to a vector image and to do that I had to use `VectorDrawableCompat` programmatically. All of the sudden I'm getting exceptions for that notification because it can not find the resource.

This is the exception:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi-v4/vector_name.png from xml type xml resource ID #0x7f0201d5
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3733)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3680)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:2215)
       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.create(VectorDrawableCompat.java:408)
```

This is the code I'm running:

```
VectorDrawableCompat vector = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.vector_name, null);
```

My gradle file has this line `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` and like I said, all other vectors are working fine but I'm mostly using them using `AppCompatImageView`.

EDIT: I should mention I'm doing this inside a library module.

Comment: It may be something the developers forgot to add to the support library. You could raise an issue on google developers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line inside the `defaultConfig` block in your `build.gradle` file:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

This will generate the pngs for APIs lower than 21 at runtime and you won't get an error because they are not found.